# CoffeeScript Undefined

Tags: coffeescript, undefined

In javascript to check if a variable was never created, we just do

```
if (typeof MyVariable !== "undefined"){ ... }
```

I was wonder how I do that in coffeescript?... I try something like

```
if (MyVariable?false){ ... }
```

but this check if `MyVariable` is a function if so that will call MyVariable(false) if not that will call void(0) or something like that.

Comment: See also [coffeescript not null or undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20010245/1048572)

Comment: Try `if  MyVariable isnt undefined` which produces `if (MyVariable !== void 0)`.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Finally I found this easy way to do it:

```
if (MyVariable?){ ... }
```

that will generate:

```
if (typeof MyVariable !== "undefined" && MyVariable !== null){ ... }
```

**UPDATE 04/07/2014**
[Demo Link](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20(myVariable%3F)%0A%20%20alert%20'myVariable%20is%20valid')

[image]

Comment: The question mark is the way to go. It's in the very first code example block of http://coffeescript.org/ - alert "I knew it!" if elvis?

Comment: Actually it only generated `item != null`

Comment: @Pencilcheck - that's because the compiler determined that item was defined in your code. (also, great name - though it's tablet check for me now :)

This answer also picks up null values which are very different from undefined. It seems like an answer to a different question IMHO

Comment: @Seth, yes I get burned by that nuance all the time, which raises the next logical question: does CS offer any syntactical shortcut for the following:

    MyVariable = MyMethod;
    if MyVariable?...

where MyMethod might return `undefined`? Or must you then resort to `if typeof myVariable isnt 'undefined'`?

Comment: @neverfox the latter as far as I'm aware (undefined type check) - CoffeeScript thinks that null and undefined should be conflated.

Comment: @Seth, not really. Non-strict comparisons (`==` and `!=`) actually treat `null` and `undefined` as equal values, so `item != null` actually tests both for `null` and `undefined` at the same time. It does not, if it's written as `item !== null`.

Comment: undefined and null are not handled as same values. undefined value can pass null check. simply use "if not item"

Comment: To bring my two cents, I have found out that `if(myVar?) {...}` really translates to `if (typeof myVar !== 'undefined' && myVar !== null) {...}` while if we are checking for an object property, such as `@myVar` or `obj.hisVar` it always translates to `if(this.myVar !== null) {..}` or `if(obj.hisVar !== null) {...}`. To remove the confusion and possible errors I recommend using the [@soundslikeneon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9929551/598500) solution here.

Answer (score 26):

First, to answer your question:

```
if typeof myVariable isnt 'undefined' then # do stuff
```

Magrangs' solution will work in most cases, except when you need to distinguish between undefined and false (for example, if myVariable can be true, false or undefined).

And just to point out, you shouldn't be wrapping your conditions in parentheses, and you shouldn't be using curly braces.

The `then` keyword can be used if everything is on the same line, otherwise use indentation to indicate what code is inside of the condition.

```
if something  
    # this is inside the if-statement  
# this is back outside of the if-statement
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The `isnt` keyword is equivalent to `!=` in Coffeescript, and may be more readable if you're used to javascript.

Comment: Equivalent to `!==`, not `!=`

Comment: This is the most specific answer - many of the others also interact with null values. Thx

Comment: @MischaArefiev `!=` in Coffee, which translates to `!==` in JavaScript.

Answer (score 14):

**This answer is for an older version of coffeescript.  See [Jaider's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238211/539490) if you want a more up to date answer (as of July 2014)**

[This coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:if%20not%20MyVariable%3F%0A%20%20MyVariable%20%3D%20%22assign%20a%20value%22) does what you want I think:

```
if not MyVariable?
  MyVariable = "assign a value"
```

Which produces:

```
if (!(typeof MyVariable !== "undefined" && MyVariable !== null)) {
  MyVariable = "assign a value";
}
```

N.b. if you make an assignment to `MyVariable` first, even if you set `MyVariable` to undefined as in [this code](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0AMyVariable%20%3D%20a.a_non_existant_property%20%23%20that%20will%20evaluate%20to%20undefined%20as%20CoffeeScript%20does%20not%20let%20you%20assign%20undefined%0A%0Aalert%20typeof%20MyVariable%20%20%23%20just%20to%20show%20it's%20undefined%0A%0Aif%20not%20MyVariable%3F%20%20%23the%20coercive%20!%3D%20equality%20operator%20is%20suitable%20here%20as%20MyVariable%20then%20becomes%20equivalent%20to%20null%0A%20%20MyVariable%20%3D%20%22assign%20a%20value%22%0Aelse%0A%20%20alert%20%22this%20shouldn't%20print%22%0A%0Aif%20MyVariable%3F%20then%20alert%20%22This%20should%20be%20printed%22%0A), then this compiles to:

```
if (!(MyVariable != null)) {
  MyVariable = "assign a value";
}
```

I believe this works because the `!=` used by CoffeeScripts `Existential Operator` (the question mark) coerces `undefined` to be equal to `null`.

p.s. Can you actually get `if (MyVariable?false){ ... }` to work?  It doesn't compile for me unless there's a space between the existential operator and false i.e. `MyVariable? false` which then makes CoffeeScript check it like a function because of the `false` which it thinks is a parameter for your `MyVariable`, [for example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20=%20%7B%7D%0AMyVariable%20=%20a.a_non_existant_property%20#%20that%20will%20evaluate%20to%20undefined%20as%20CoffeeScript%20does%20not%20let%20you%20assign%20this%20yourself%0A%0Aalert%20typeof%20MyVariable%20%20#%20just%20to%20show%20it%27s%20undefined%0A%0Aif%20not%20MyVariable?%20%20#the%20coercive%20!=%20equality%20operator%20is%20suitable%20here%20as%20MyVariable%20then%20becomes%20equivalent%20to%20null%0A%20%20MyVariable%20=%20%22assign%20a%20value%22%0Aelse%0A%20%20alert%20%22this%20shouldn%27t%20print%22%0A%0Aif%20MyVariable?%20then%20alert%20%22This%20should%20be%20printed%22%0A):

```
if MyVariable? false
  alert "Would have attempted to call MyVariable as a function"
else
  alert "but didn't call MyVariable as it wasn't a function"
```

Produces:

```
if (typeof MyVariable === "function" ? MyVariable(false) : void 0) {
  alert("Would have attempted to call MyVariable as a function");
} else {
  alert("but didn't call MyVariable as it wasn't a function");
}
```

Comment: this is old coffee script.  the `variable?` now only compiles to variable != null

Comment: @Gambai are you sure?  The website still shows `... !== null` http://coffeescript.org/#try:variable%3F

Comment: Yes, the compiler now sometimes omits the **!= undefined** as an optimization because when the variable should be defined somewhere in the code. I say _should_ because the compiler does not always work correctly...

Comment: @Suzana_K good to know.  I'm sure people coming across this question would like an up to date answer, please feel free to edit mine or post a new answer and I'll link to it from the top of mine.  I don't use CoffeeScript anymore after adopting ES6 / TypeScript so I can't update the answer.  Actually it looks like Jaider's answer covers it:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10238211/539490

Answer (score 11):

```
typeof MyVariable isnt "undefined"
```

from [js2coffee](http://js2coffee.org/)

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [Jaider's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929306/coffeescript-undefined#answer-10238211) above *(I couldn't comment due to insufficient reputation)*, be careful that it's a different case if it's something inside an object/array:

```
someArray['key']?
```

will be converted to:

```
someArray['key'] != null
```

Screenshot from [js2coffee.org](http://js2coffee.org):

[image: js2coffee.org]

Comment: You're checking if the key exists, so this makes sense.

If you also need to check if the array exists, try someArray?['key']?

Answer (score 7):

I just use:

```
if (myVariable)
    //do stuff
```

As undefined is falsy it will only do stuff if myVariable is not undefined.

You just have to be aware that it will 'do stuff' for values that are 0, "" and null

Comment: I prefer this method as long as `myVariable` isn't allowed to be a falsy value like `null` or `0`.

Answer (score 3):

The cleanest way I've found to assign a variable to an undefined and not-null variable is using `unless`:

```
unless ( myVar? )
    myVar = 'val'
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the OR idiom?

```
myVar or 'val'
```

So, the result will equal myVar, unless it is undefined in which case it will equal 'val'.

Comment: With this idiom any falsish value will return 'val' instead of whatever it supposed to be — including `''`, `0.0` and `false`. Which is, probably, not unwanted.