# coffee script testing if not defined

Tags: coffeescript

according to the coffee script site

```
console.log(s) if s?
```

should generate

```
if (typeof s !== "undefined" && s !== null) {
    console.log(s);
}
```

But what is showing up in my browser is

```
  if (s != null) {
      return console.log(s);
  }
```

Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2), coffee-rails (3.2.2), rails-backbone (0.7.2), rails (3.2.13)

Here is my coffee script function.  any thoughts on why I am not getting what coffee script site says I should??

```
window.p = (s) ->
    console.log(s) if s?
```

Comment: Interesting. But potentially correct. Can `s` be undefined in your situation? It is defined as a function argument.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CoffeeScript Undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9929306/coffeescript-undefined) (not really the question, but the answers and comments discuss this detail)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you say just a bare:

```
console.log(s) if s?
```

then you will indeed get the JavaScript you're expecting ([demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:console.log%28s%29%20if%20s?)):

```
if (typeof s !== "undefined" && s !== null) {
  console.log(s);
}
```

However, if `s` is a known variable such as here:

```
f = (s) -> console.log(s) if s?
```

then you'll get ([demo](http://coffeescript.org/#try:f%20=%20%28s%29%20-%3E%20console.log%28s%29%20if%20s?%0A)):

```
if (s != null) {
  //...
}
```

for the `s?` test.

So why the difference? In the first case, CoffeeScript cannot guarantee that there is an `s` variable in existence anywhere so it must do a `typeof s` check in order to avoid a `ReferenceError` exception.

However, if `s` is known to exist because it is a function parameter or has been assigned to as a local variable (so that CoffeeScript will produce a `var s`), then you don't need the `typeof s` check since you cannot, in this case, get a `ReferenceError`.

That leaves us with `s !== null` versus `s != null`. Dropping down to non-strict inequality (`s != null`) allows you to check if `s` is `undefined` or `null` with a single comparison. When you check `typeof s !== "undefined"`, you wrapping the `undefined` test in with the "is there an `s` variable" check and a strict `s !== null` test is all that you need to check for `null`.

Comment: By Javascript (Ecmascript) standards `undefined` and `null` are `==` equal, so `s==null` is an old and well established usage.  But many lint standards object to the use of `==`.  It's one the issues you have address if compiled coffeescript has to be lint approved.

Answer (score 2):

You're right,

```
(s) -> console.log(s) if s?

console.log(x) if x?
```

compiles to

```
(function(s) {
  if (s != null) {
    return console.log(s);
  }
});

if (typeof x !== "undefined" && x !== null) {
  console.log(x);
}
```

It looks like the CoffeeScript compiler is optimizing the Javascript a little bit for you, because in the case of a function argument like this, `typeof s` will never be `undefined` as `s` is defined right there in the function signature, even if its value is `null`.

Comment: here is live example

http://coffeescript.org/#try:(s)%20-%3E%20console.log(s)%20if%20s%3F%0A%0Aconsole.log(x)%20if%20x%3F