# coffeescript not null or undefined behavior

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, existential-operator

so i'm playing around with [coffee-script](http://js2coffee.org/) and got this behavior:

`a?` will translate to `typeof a !== "undefined" && a !== null;` - that's fine

the problem is if i try the same for `a.foo?`. this time it translate to `a.foo != null;`
the same result i get for `a[foo]` also.

is there a "fast" way to check if `a.foo` is not null or undefined like there is with a?