# AngularJs best practice to check if undefined and null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement, null, undefined

I would like to know which way to check if a variable is `null`or `undefined` in AngularJS is the best way.

**First way:**

```
if(!myVar){...}
```

**Second way:**

```
if(myVar === null || myVar === undefined){...}
```

**Third way:**

```
if(angular.isUndefined(myVar) || myVar === null){...}
```

I prefere the first one but I want to be sure if it's the best way.

The problem with the last one is that I use an angular's function to test if it's undefined and a native JavaScript way to check if it's null.

Comment: Use OR condition instead of and.

Comment: The first way also includes falsy values like false, 0, "".

Comment: @MichaelLiu True, although in many cases that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it, which is the route that [Coffeescript too goes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10238211/987185), is:

```
if (typeof MyVariable === "undefined" || MyVariable === null){ ... }
```

Comment: What is it about this approach that makes it _the best_? I wonder what it was about this that led the makers of Coffeescript to choose this method.

Comment: Did a little more research and found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null) that talks about a little bit about why this method is better. Has to do with reference errors. But I still wonder if this truly is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I think which depend of the situation, usually i use the first way since usually I validate when the variable is 0, empty array, undefined or null,if you goal is validate only the values null and undefined i think wich the second way is the ideally, and the third way is good but force to denpend of the angular.